# Range.Find to return the correct value based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import tasks from one sheet(WS) to the main tracker sheet (Sub Tasks),. The import sheet has milestones and then sub tasks within each Milestone.

My code imports the milestones then goes back and imports the sub tasks for each milestone. However, if the milestones being added have the same title as ones already in the Sub Task sheet, it will add the sub tasks to the inocrrect milestone. I am using Range.Find, i understand it would find the first match, which is not want i want all the time. So i want to add criteria in, so if a match if found, and the value in column H is equal to the value in the N9 in the worksheet, and then value in Sub Task Column I is equal to the value in value N10 in WS, then add.

If not, find next and test again. However, i cannot seem to get it to work.

**UPDATED**

```
                If .Cells(findactivityintasks.row, TDSNumCol).Value = ImportWs.Range("N9").Value And .Cells(findactivityintasks.row, MileStoneNumCol).Value = DeliverableActivity Then
                    newdeliverablerow = (findactivityintasks.row)
                Else
                    Do
                        Set findactivityintasks = .Range("B3:B" & lastrowsubtasks1).FindNext(findactivityintasks)
                    Loop Until .Cells(findactivityintasks.row, TDSNumCol).Value = ImportWs.Range("N9").Value And .Cells(findactivityintasks.row, MileStoneNumCol).Value = DeliverableActivity
                    newdeliverablerow = (findactivityintasks.row)
                End If
```

**ALL CODE FOR SUB**

```
'Add Milestone to subtask sheets
For Each cell In ImportWs.Range("B" & activityStart & ":B" & activityend)
NewRowSubTasks = lastrowsubtasks + i
DeliverableActivity = Int(cell.Offset(0, -1).Value)
    With subtaskws
        .Range(SubTaskCol & NewRowSubTasks & ":" & lastcollet & NewRowSubTasks).Interior.ColorIndex = 16
        .Range(SubTaskCol & NewRowSubTasks & ":" & lastcollet & NewRowSubTasks).Font.ColorIndex = 2
        .Range(SubTaskCol & NewRowSubTasks & ":" & lastcollet & NewRowSubTasks).Font.Size = 12
        .Range(IDCol & NewRowSubTasks).Interior.ColorIndex = 23
        .Range(IDCol & NewRowSubTasks).Font.ColorIndex = 2
        .Range(IDCol & NewRowSubTasks).Font.Size = 16
        .Range(IDCol & NewRowSubTasks).NumberFormat = "0"
        .Cells(NewRowSubTasks, SubTaskCol).Value = ImportWs.Range("B" & cell.row).Value
        .Cells(NewRowSubTasks, IDCol).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((subtaskws.Range("A" & NewRowSubTasks - 1).Value + 0.01), 0)
        .Cells(NewRowSubTasks, TDSNumCol).Value = ImportWs.Range("N9").Value
        .Cells(NewRowSubTasks, MileStoneNumCol).Value = DeliverableActivity
        .Cells(NewRowSubTasks, BWLCol).Value = ImportWs.Range("L" & cell.row).Value
    End With
    i = i + 1
Next cell

'find start and end of deliverables
DeliverableStart = valuePos(ImportWs, "C:G", "Outputs / Deliverables") + 1
DeliverableEnd = valuePos(ImportWs, "A:G", "Tools / constraints") - 1


'find deliverables to add to Milestones and find what Milestones to add them too
For Each cell In ImportWs.Range("C" & DeliverableStart & ":C" & DeliverableEnd)
    DeliverableActivity = Int(cell.Offset(0, -1).Value)
    Set finddeliverableactivity = ImportWs.Range("A" & activityStart & ":A" & activityend).Find(What:=("# " & (DeliverableActivity + 1)), Lookat:=xlWhole)
        If finddeliverableactivity Is Nothing Then
            With subtaskws
                Dim lastrowsubtasks1 As Long
                lastrowsubtasks1 = subtaskws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
                newdeliverablerow = (lastrowsubtasks1 + 1)
                .Range("A" & (newdeliverablerow)).EntireRow.Insert
                newrow = newdeliverablerow
                .Range("A4").EntireRow.Copy
                .Range("A" & newrow).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                .Range("A" & newrow).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation
                .Range("A" & newrow).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats
                .Range("A" & newrow & ":AE" & newrow & "").ClearContents
                .Columns("A:BB").Calculate
                .Range(IDCol & newrow).Value = subtaskws.Range("A" & newrow).Offset(-1, 0).Value + 0.01
                .Cells(newrow, SubTaskCol).Value = cell.Value
                .Cells(newrow, FormatCol).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                .Cells(newrow, AcceptanceCriteriacol).Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                .Cells(newrow, TargetDateCol).Value = cell.Offset(0, 9).Value
                .Cells(newrow, BWLCol).Value = cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
                .Cells(newrow, TDSNumCol).Value = ImportWs.Range("N9").Value
                .Cells(newrow, MileStoneNumCol).Value = DeliverableActivity
                .Cells(newrow, AWCol).Value = "=SUM(AF" & newrow & ":" & lastcollet & newrow & ")"
                .Cells(newrow, PCol).Value = "=(" & WCol & newrow & "*" & ICol & newrow & "*" & ECol & newrow & ")"
                .Cells(newrow, LevelCol).Value = "=IF(" & PCol & newrow & " >11,1,IF(" & PCol & newrow & ">3,2,""N/A""))"
                .Range("A" & newrow).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End With
            Exit Sub
        Else
            With subtaskws
                lastrowsubtasks1 = subtaskws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
                activityrow = finddeliverableactivity.row
                ActivtiyforDeliverable = ImportWs.Range("B" & activityrow).Value
                Set findactivityintasks = .Range("B3:B" & lastrowsubtasks1).Find(What:=(ActivtiyforDeliverable), Lookat:=xlWhole)
                newdeliverablerow = (findactivityintasks.row)
                .Range("A" & (newdeliverablerow)).EntireRow.Insert
                newrow = newdeliverablerow
                .Range("A4").EntireRow.Copy
                .Range("A" & newrow).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                .Range("A" & newrow).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation
                .Range("A" & newrow).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats
                .Range("A" & newrow & ":AE" & newrow & "").ClearContents
                .Columns("A:BB").Calculate
                .Range(IDCol & newrow).Value = subtaskws.Range("A" & newrow).Offset(-1, 0).Value + 0.01
                .Cells(newrow, SubTaskCol).Value = cell.Value
                .Cells(newrow, FormatCol).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                .Cells(newrow, AcceptanceCriteriacol).Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                .Cells(newrow, TargetDateCol).Value = cell.Offset(0, 9).Value
                .Cells(newrow, BWLCol).Value = cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
                .Cells(newrow, TDSNumCol).Value = ImportWs.Range("N9").Value
                .Cells(newrow, MileStoneNumCol).Value = DeliverableActivity
                .Cells(newrow, AWCol).Value = "=SUM(AF" & newrow & ":" & lastcollet & newrow & ")"
                .Cells(newrow, PCol).Value = "=(" & WCol & newrow & "*" & ICol & newrow & "*" & ECol & newrow & ")"
                .Cells(newrow, LevelCol).Value = "=IF(" & PCol & newrow & " >11,1,IF(" & PCol & newrow & ">3,2,""N/A""))"
                .Range("A" & newrow).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End With
        End If

Next cell

Call CompactView

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: In the VBA IDE put the cursor on on the Keyword FindNext and press F1.

Comment: Sorry i am unaware of what IDE is,

Comment: Its the interface you use when editing VBA code.

Comment: So the MS website says to do a loop until both criteria are matched? Would this be the best way

Comment: the base loop is what you find [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext)

Comment: I am not quite understanding what i would loop. I have updated the code to include what i have so far. But it seems to do a continuous loop

Comment: You don't actually do anything in your loop so that might be why it never stops.

Comment: Is my loop not finding each value to then test against the criteria?

Comment: Apologies, it does do that, but if your loop doesn't end then the conditions are presumably never met.

Comment: Hm strange, there is data that it can match with in sheet. I will re-try

Comment: I keep checking and there is data that it can match with as in code before this i add that data in.

Comment: My code works fine if theres no duplicates of Milestone names, its perfect but if there is it adds it in the wrong location